# jQuery Waypoints add class when element is scrolled into view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) plugin to check if an element is scrolled into view. I have multiple divs with class `item` as the user scrolls down the page, I want to add a class "viewed" to each.

```
$(".item").waypoint(function(){
    $(this).addClass("viewed");
    console.log("yey");
});
```

The console.log works, but the `.addClass` doesn't. Does the plugin not support `$(this)`?

Comment: What does `console.log($(this));` return?

Comment: @JoshSpears - http://puu.sh/nmxiA/f7120da88f.png

Comment: get the target from args or event like parameters and print the sender target

Comment: http://puu.sh/nmxrt/a79c48d663.png

Comment: if you pass event like parameters what do you get?

Comment: do you have how like you get element object from the waypoint?

Comment: $('button.find-by-element').on('click', function() {
  var element = document.getElementById('overflow-scroll')
  var context = Waypoint.Context.findByElement(element)
  if (typeof context === 'undefined') {
    notify('Context does not exist')
  }
  else if (context instanceof Waypoint.Context) {
    notify('Context found')
  }
})

Comment: not sure what you mean?...

Comment: that the was code i send you , there is how you get target element fire handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working.

```
$(".item").waypoint(function(){
   $(this[0,'element']).addClass("viewed");
});
```

The `this` wasn't pointed at the element, so I needed to target it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when calling these callback functions, and what *this* really means.   In this instance, its probably referring to your function.

Doesn't the event trigger pass the target in the function as an argument?  Try using that.  If you want to know what your nested *this* really is, console.log it.

```
$(".item").waypoint(function(thing){
   $(thing).addClass("viewed");
   console.log("yey");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The checked answer caused loads of errors in newer version of this plugin.

This is what works for me:

```
$(".item").waypoint(function() {
    $(this.element).addClass("viewed");
});
```