# Jquery waypoint index equals always zero

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to get the index of the type (here: h2). But when I scroll it is always 0.

```
$("h2").waypoint(function(e) {
    alert($(this.element).index());
})
```

Comment: post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: There's no such property `element` on the Element object referenced from `this`, so your current logic will be creating an error as you're trying to use `undefined` in a jQuery selector. Presumably you need to use just `$(this).index()` instead.

Comment: Are you using this jquery-waypoints package?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661889/jquery-waypoints-add-class-when-element-is-scrolled-into-view